# Swagger (spray) path parameters inside resource url

Tags: scala, swagger, spray

Say I have a parametrized resource url like

```
/customers/{CUSTOMER-ID}/ownedItems/{ITEM-ID}
```

How should I annotatate/split my spray routes (using the spray-swagger plugin) to generate a documentation that will recognize {CUSTOMER-ID} as a proper path parameter?

My problem is that the top level @Api annotation takes a path but no parameters, while the @ApiOperation can be annotated with path parameters but these get appended at the end. In other words, if I write:

```
@Api(value = "/customers/{CUSTOMER-ID}")

@ApiOperation(httpMethod = "GET")
@ApiImplicitParams(Array(
new ApiImplicitParam(name = "ITEM-ID", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "path"))
```

I get in the UI only ITEM-ID as testable parameter, while CUSTOMER-ID, while being reported as in { }, is just a string.

I'd like to have something where both are path parameters.

Any idea?

Comment: Not a response so far, not even in PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**customers** is your @Api entry point, not path parameters. Path parameters must be used only into @ApiOperation as follow (with more samples) :

```
@Api(value = "/customers")

@ApiOperation(value = "/{CUSTOMER-ID}/ownedItems/{ITEM-ID}", httpMethod = "GET")
@ApiImplicitParams(Array(
  new ApiImplicitParam(name = "CUSTOMER-ID", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "path"),
  new ApiImplicitParam(name = "ITEM-ID", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "path"))

@ApiOperation(value = "/{CUSTOMER-ID}", httpMethod = "GET")
@ApiImplicitParams(Array(
  new ApiImplicitParam(name = "CUSTOMER-ID", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "path"))

@ApiOperation(value = "/", httpMethod = "POST")
```